# "Благой смены" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Благой смены" — можно ли так сказать?
(Речь идет о ночной смене на работе.)

Answer (score 3):

Сочетание высокопарно-книжно-религиозного прилагательного, сохранившегося лишь в составе устойчивых выражений, с канцелярски-прозаическим существительным может вызвать недопонимание. По крайней мере, заставит задуматься на полминуты. Без иронии такое пожелание можно было бы разве что вложить в уста персонажу вроде церковного батюшки, напр. напутствующего Хому Брута перед ночной службой. Это примерно как поздравить юбиляра с "тезоименитством" или предложить "имплементировать" то, о чём договорились.

Answer (score 0):

"Благой смены" - это родительный падеж?

Дошло, знаете ли! )))

Это пожелание, восклицательное предложение!

Ночная смена самая тяжёлая, вот и желают благой - то есть хорошей, удачной, доброй, без происшествий - смены.

*"Благой (вам) смены!"*

Просто в современной речи слово "[благой](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20)" крайне редко употребляется вне идиом *благим матом* и *благие намерения*.